# Sqlite3 'executemany' with UPDATE and INSERT using python dictionary keys not acting the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

I have two sqlite queries that use executemany to insert and update data sets from a python dictionary.  With the `insert` query the `dictionary.values()` as the executemany second argument works perfectly, but with the update I do not get anything updated.  Can someone please shed some light on why there is a differrence?
Insert code sample:

```
query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO farm_tb(farm_id, farm)\
           VALUES(:frmid, :frm)"
cur.executemany(query, arr.values())
conn.commit()
```

Update sample:

```
query = ("UPDATE emp_log_tb SET syncstatus=syncstatus WHERE log_id=log_id", (':syncstatus', ':logid'))
 cur.executemany(query, arr.values())
 conn.commit()
```

Both data sets looks similar:
insert data:

```
{'0': {'farmid': '4', 'farm': 'farm1'}, '1': {'farmid': '3', 'farm': 'farm6'}}
```

update data:

```
{'0': {'logid': '1', 'syncstatus': 1}, '1': {'logid': '2', 'syncstatus': 1}, '2': {'logid': '3', 'syncstatus': 1}, '3': {'logid': '4', 'syncstatus': 1}, '4': {'logid': '5', 'syncstatus': 1}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That update statement just sets every row's `syncstatus` to its current value, because `log_id = log_id` is always true (Unless it's a `NULL`, of course). Plus you're assigning a tuple to `query`, not a string. Not sure what `executemany()` does with that.

You want something like

```
cur.executemany("UPDATE emp_log_tb SET syncstatus=:syncstatus WHERE log_id=:log_id", arr.values())
```

Note the named parameters in the `UPDATE` like the ones in the `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great.  Can you please tell me why it works with the keys as named parameters and the ```dictionary.values()``` as second argument?  The reason I am asking is the second argument is essentially passing ```{logid: 1, syncstatus: 1}``` key:value pairs with the key as the placeholder for the value.  In a previous comment on another thread you referred to ```executemany``` expecting a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

`"UPDATE emp_log_tb SET syncstatus=syncstatus WHERE log_id=log_id", (':syncstatus', ':logid')`
should be 
`UPDATE emp_log_tb SET syncstatus=:syncstatus WHERE log_id=:log_id`